# Possible to load image objects directly into jquery colorbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gallery, colorbox

I'm using the **jQuery** plugin "colorbox" and I need to be able to dynamically load the colorbox with a list of preloaded image objects.

The problem is, I have 3 image sizes, thumbnail, display, and large.  I use the thumbnail and display with a gallery plugin, however I would like to add the feature that when the display image is clicked it will pull up a colorbox of the large images.
I can get an array of the large images, however, I have yet to find a way to load them into colorbox as a group.

I can load one image using:

```
$.fn.colorbox({href: '/path/to/image.jpg'});
```

Is it possible to pass the href a comma seperated list? or an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can not currently do something like that with ColorBox.  To display as a group the elements must be in your document.  The reason for this is that ColorBox stores settings for each picture individually on the target element. Additionally, it uses the document to search for and order the items in the group.

Answer (score 0):

Add a div with inline style to make it invisible. Inside this div, place your list of images.

```
<div style="display: none;">
    <img src="#path" />
</div>
```